Why canvas size are smaller on iphone 13 then android?
I'm creating a website with angular 16 and using bootstrap 5.3.3. Somethings don't work on iPhone 13 but works on iphone 8. For example, I have a canvas inside a bootstrap column
<div class="col-md-8 col-12 p-2">
  <div class="sale-content">
    <span class="total-sales ms-3">TOTAL SALES</span>
    <div class="ag-chart-canvas">
      <canvas width="1122" height="900" style="width: 374px; height: 300px;" tabindex="-1" role="img" aria-label="chart, 1 series"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>            
</div>

.ag-charts-canvas {
    display: block !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}

On desktop and android this works well, but on iPhone 13, Google Chrome  Browers doesn't work.
Note: iphone 8 the same solution work.
Screenshot - iphone not working
Screenshot - android/desktop working
I tried put the canva display as block and width with 100%, but doesn't work.
I can't reproduce this scenario using chrome user agent

I'm facing the same problem.
